# UAC manifest file

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have an exe, for which I have created a manifest file shown in URL:

- [change exe option to run as administrator by bat script on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/360568/change-exe-option-to-run-as-administrator-by-bat-script-on-windows-7/361944#361944)

The problem is that, the exe writes the output to a child window. For eg, if my exe were to print dir of C:\, when the exe is run, the output is printed on a separate window and goes off in a split second.

So, my question is, is there a way to redirect the output from this child window?

- I am trying to implement all of this in a batch script.
- I have no idea of vb scripting either.

Comment: What happens if you do (from an administrative command prompt) `exeName.exe > testfile.txt` does a file called testfile.txt get created in the directory you where in with the text from the output of the exe?